# how to use french letters in a django template?

Tags: python, django, unicode

I have some french letters (é, è, à...) in a django template but when it is loaded by django, an UnicodeDecodeError exception is raised.

If I don't load the template but directly use a python string. It works ok.

Is there something to do to use unicode with django template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably storing the template in a non-unicode encoding, such as latin-1.  I believe Django assumes that templates are in UTF-8 by default (though there is a setting to override this).

Your editor should be capable of saving the template file in the UTF-8 encoding (probably via a dropdown on the save as page, though this may depend on your editor).  Re-save the file as UTF-8, and the error should go away.

Comment: Pedantification: Latin-1 is not more "none-unicode" than UTF-8. Both are not unicode, but encodings. UTF-8 can encode all unicode characters of Unicode, and Latin-1 can't but they are still not unicode. It doesn't change the validity of your answer, I'm just being pedantic for no particular reason. ;)

Comment: I'm all for being pedantic, but I should point out I used the phrase "non-unicode encoding", not just "non-unicode", which is accurate.  UTF-8 is indeed an encoding (one of several) for unicode data, whereas latin-1 is not, as it cannot represent all possible unicode codepoints.

Comment: My IDE displayed my file as being `UTF-8` and only after opening the same file in Notepad++ did I see it was in fact `UTF-8 without BOM`. I saved it as plain `UTF-8` and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

This is from the [Django unicode documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#templates) related to your problem:

" But the common case is to read templates from the filesystem, and this creates a slight complication: not all filesystems store their data encoded as UTF-8. If your template files are not stored with a UTF-8 encoding, set the [FILE_CHARSET](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#setting-FILE_CHARSET) setting to the encoding of the files on disk. When Django reads in a template file, it will convert the data from this encoding to Unicode. ([FILE_CHARSET](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#setting-FILE_CHARSET) is set to 'utf-8' by default.)

The [DEFAULT_CHARSET](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#setting-DEFAULT_CHARSET) setting controls the encoding of rendered templates. This is set to UTF-8 by default. "